# \newgeometry with elsarticle.cls

Tags: geometry, elsarticle

I am preparing an article with elsarticle.cls for an Elsevier Journal. Within the document, I need to reset geometry. I receive the error `Undefined control sequence. \newgeometry` MWE is as follows:

```
\documentclass[12pt,preprint,authoryear]{elsarticle}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{natbib}
\journal{ABC Journal}
\begin{document}
    \begin{frontmatter}
     \title{A Sample Article}
      \author{Ahmed Arif}
       \address{Lahore} 
 \maketitle{}
\begin{abstract}
       Abstract of the paper is here. 
 \end{abstract}
\end{frontmatter}

\section{Introduction} 
 This is introduction. 
   \newgeometry{top=3cm,left=1cm,right=1cm,bottom=3cm}
     \begin{landscape}
    I want to place a table here. 
     \end{landscape}
   \restoregeometry
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `lscape` package

```
\documentclass[12pt,preprint,authoryear]{elsarticle}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{newtxtext,geometry,lscape}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{natbib}
\journal{ABC Journal}
\begin{document}
    \begin{frontmatter}
     \title{A Sample Article}
      \author{Ahmed Arif}
       \address{Lahore}
 \maketitle{}
\begin{abstract}
       Abstract of the paper is here.
 \end{abstract}
\end{frontmatter}

\section{Introduction}
 This is introduction.
   \newgeometry{top=3cm,left=1cm,right=1cm,bottom=3cm}
     \begin{landscape}
    I want to place a table here.
     \end{landscape}
   \restoregeometry
\end{document}
```

An alternative would be the `rotating` package.